# C code using process synchronization and multi-threading

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

This is a matrix-vector multiplication program using multi-threading. It takes matrixfile.txt and vectorfile.txt names, buffer size, and number of splits as input and splits the matrixfile into splitfiles in main function (matrix is divided into smaller parts). Then mapper threads writes the value into buffer and reducer thread writes result into resultfile.txt. Resultfile algorithm is not efficient but the code works which I tested with various inputs.

I appreciate any correction and comment.

***Program:***

```
/* -*- linux-c -*- */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "common.h"
#include "stdint.h"

const int ROWS = 10000;
const int COLS = 3;

int twodimen[10000][3]; 
int count_lines;
int vector[10000];
int vector_lines;
int NUMBER_OF_ROWS;
int splitnum;
int INPUT_BUF_SIZE;
sem_t *sem_mutex;       /* protects the buffer */
sem_t *sem_full;        /* counts the number of items */
sem_t *sem_empty;       /* counts the number of empty buffer slots */

void * mapperThread(void * xx){
  int filecount = (intptr_t)xx;
  char filename[20] = "splitfile";
  char txt[5] = ".txt";
  char num[10];
  sprintf(num, "%d", filecount);
  strcat(filename, num);
  strcat(filename, txt);  
  printf ("mapper thread started with: %s \n", filename);  
  struct buffer * bp = find(filecount);

  // OPENING SPLIT FILE
  FILE *splitfileptr; 
  char *sline = NULL;
  size_t slen = 0;
  ssize_t sread;

  splitfileptr = fopen(filename, "r");   
  if (splitfileptr == NULL){  
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while ((sread = getline(&sline, &slen, splitfileptr)) != -1) {
    char *line_copy = strdup(sline);
    if (SYNCHRONIZED) {
      sem_wait(sem_empty);
      sem_wait(sem_mutex);
      // CRITICAL SECTION BEGIN
      bp->buf[bp->in] = line_copy; 
      bp->count = bp->count + 1;
      bp->in = (bp->in + 1) % INPUT_BUF_SIZE; // incrementing buffer count, updating
      // CRITICAL SECTION END 
      sem_post(sem_mutex); // releasing the mutex
      sem_post(sem_full);  // incrementing full count, sem_post is signal operation          
    } 
  }
  printf("producer ended; bye...\n");
  pthread_exit(0);  
}

void * reducerThread(char* resultfilename){
   printf("reducer thread started\n");     
   FILE *resultfileptr;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   char* item;      
   int index = 0;
   while (index  < count_lines) {
     for(int i = 0; i < splitnum; i++){
        struct buffer * bp = find(i);
        if (SYNCHRONIZED && bp->count != 0) {          
          sem_wait(sem_full); // checks whether buffer has item to retrieve, if full count = 0, this statement will cause consumer to wait
          sem_wait(sem_mutex);  // makes sure when we are executing this section no other process executes at the buffer
          // CRITICAL SECTION BEGIN
          item = bp->buf[bp->out]; // just retrieving the buffer. putting into item.
          bp->count = bp->count - 1;          
          bp->out = (bp->out + 1) % INPUT_BUF_SIZE; // updating out index variable, this is a circular bufer
          index++;
          printf("retrieved item is: %s", item); 
          twodimen[atoi(&item[0]) - 1][0] = atoi(&item[0]);  
          twodimen[atoi(&item[0]) - 1][2] = twodimen[atoi(&item[0]) - 1 ][2] + atoi(&item[4]) * vector[atoi(&item[2]) - 1];
          // CRITICAL SECTION END
          sem_post(sem_mutex); //
          sem_post(sem_empty); // number of empty cells in the buffer should be 1 more. incrementing empty size.           
        } 
     }
   }
   // WRITING TO RESULTFILE
   resultfileptr = fopen(resultfilename, "w+");
   for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
       if(twodimen[i][j] != 0 && twodimen[i][j + 2] != 0){
         char str[10];
         sprintf(str, "%d %d \n", twodimen[i][j], twodimen[i][j + 2]);
         fprintf(resultfileptr, "%s", str);      
       }
     }
   }
   printf("consumer ended; bye...\n");
   fflush (stdout); 
   pthread_exit(NULL);   
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  clock_t start_time = clock();
  const char *const matrixfilename = argv[1];
  const char *const vectorfilename = argv[2];
  const char *const resultfilename = argv[3];
  const int K = atoi(argv[4]);
  INPUT_BUF_SIZE = atoi(argv[5]);
  splitnum = K; 
  printf ("mv started\n");
  printf ("%s\n", matrixfilename); 
  printf ("%s\n", vectorfilename); 
  printf ("%s\n", resultfilename);
  printf ("K is %d\n", K);
  printf ("splitnum is %d\n", splitnum);
  printf ("INPUT_BUF_SIZE is %d\n", INPUT_BUF_SIZE);

  if(INPUT_BUF_SIZE > BUFSIZE || INPUT_BUF_SIZE < 100){
    printf("Buffer input should be between 100 and 10000, BUFSIZE = 10000 will be used as default \n");
    INPUT_BUF_SIZE = BUFSIZE;
  }

  FILE *fileptr;
  count_lines = 0;
  char filechar[10000], chr;
  fileptr = fopen(matrixfilename, "r");
  // extract character from file and store it in chr
  chr = getc(fileptr);
  while(chr != EOF)
  {
    // count whenever new line is encountered
    if(chr == '\n')
    {
      count_lines = count_lines + 1;
    }
    // take next character from file
    chr = getc(fileptr);
  }
  printf("countlines is %d \n", count_lines);
  fclose(fileptr); // close file
  printf("There are %d lines in in a file\n", count_lines);

  int s = count_lines / K;
  int remainder = count_lines % K;

  printf("S is %d \n", s);

  FILE *fw, *fr;
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  // CREATING SPLIT FILES AND WRITING TO THEM
  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
    char filename[20] = "splitfile";
    char txt[5] = ".txt";
    char its[10];
    sprintf(its, "%d", i);
    strcat(filename, its);
    strcat(filename, txt);

    fw = fopen(filename, "w+");
    fr = fopen(matrixfilename, "r");
    if(i == K - 1){
    for(int j = 0; j < count_lines; j++){
        while(((read = getline(&line, &len, fr)) != -1) && j >= (i * s)){
            char *line_copy = strdup(line);
            fprintf(fw, "%s", line_copy); 
            j++;
        }
      }  
    }
    else{
    for(int j = 0; j < count_lines; j++){
        while(((read = getline(&line, &len, fr)) != -1) && j >= (i * s) && j <= (i + 1) * s - 1){
            char *line_copy = strdup(line);
            fprintf(fw, "%s", line_copy); 
            j++;
          }
      }
    }
    fclose(fw);
    fclose(fr);
  }

    FILE *vectorfileptr;
    vector_lines = 0;
    char vchr;
    vectorfileptr = fopen(vectorfilename, "r");
    vchr = getc(vectorfileptr);

    line = NULL;
    len = 0;


    // COUNTING THE SIZE OF VECTOR 
    while(vchr != EOF)
    {
      // count whenever new line is encountered
      if(vchr == '\n')
      {
        vector_lines = vector_lines + 1;
      }
      // take next character from file
      vchr = getc(vectorfileptr);
    }  
    fclose(vectorfileptr); 
    printf("There are %d lines in vector file\n", vector_lines);    


    vector[vector_lines];

    vectorfileptr = fopen(vectorfilename, "r");
    if (vectorfileptr == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    int linenumber = 0;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, vectorfileptr)) != -1) {
          char *line_copy = strdup(line);    
          vector[linenumber] = atoi(line_copy);
          linenumber++;
    }
    fclose(vectorfileptr);            
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_lines; i++){
      printf("vector %d: %d\n", i, vector[i]);
    }
  FILE *countfileptr;
  countfileptr = fopen(matrixfilename, "r");
  NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 0;
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, countfileptr)) != -1) { 
        char *line_copy = strdup(line);
        if(atoi(&line_copy[0]) > NUMBER_OF_ROWS){
          NUMBER_OF_ROWS = atoi(&line_copy[0]);
        }
  }
  fclose(countfileptr);




  /* first clean up semaphores with same names */
  sem_unlink (SEMNAME_MUTEX); 
  sem_unlink (SEMNAME_FULL); 
  sem_unlink (SEMNAME_EMPTY); 

  /* create and initialize the semaphores */
  sem_mutex = sem_open(SEMNAME_MUTEX, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0660, 1);
  if (sem_mutex < 0) {
    perror("can not create semaphore\n");
    exit (1); 
  }
  printf("sem %s created\n", SEMNAME_MUTEX);

  sem_full = sem_open(SEMNAME_FULL, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0660, 0);
  if (sem_full < 0) {
    perror("can not create semaphore\n");
    exit (1); 
  } 
  printf("sem %s created\n", SEMNAME_FULL);

  sem_empty = sem_open(SEMNAME_EMPTY, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0660, BUFSIZE); // initially bufsize items can be put 
  if (sem_empty < 0) {
    perror("can not create semaphore\n");
    exit (1); 
  } 
  printf("sem %s create\n", SEMNAME_EMPTY); 

  for(int i = 0; i < splitnum; i++){
    insertFirst(0,0,0,i);
  }

   int err;
   pthread_t tid[splitnum]; 
   printf ("starting thread\n"); 
   for(int i = 0; i < splitnum; i++){
     err = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void*) mapperThread, (void*)(intptr_t)i);
     if(err != 0){
       printf("\n Cant create thread: [%s]", strerror(err));
     }
   }
   pthread_t reducertid;
   pthread_create(&reducertid, NULL, (void*) reducerThread, (char*) resultfilename); 

   for(int i = 0; i < splitnum; i++){
     pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
   }
   pthread_join(reducertid,NULL);
   // join reducer thread
  // closing semaphores
  sem_close(sem_mutex);
  sem_close(sem_full);
  sem_close(sem_empty);
  /* remove the semaphores */
  sem_unlink(SEMNAME_MUTEX);
  sem_unlink(SEMNAME_FULL);
  sem_unlink(SEMNAME_EMPTY);
  fflush( stdout );
  exit(0);
}
```

***HEADER file:***

```
/* -*- linux-c  -*-  */

#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#define TRACE 1
#define SEMNAME_MUTEX       "/name_sem_mutex"
#define SEMNAME_FULL        "/name_sem_fullcount"
#define SEMNAME_EMPTY       "/name_sem_emptycount"   
#define ENDOFDATA -1 // marks the end of data stream from the producer
// #define SHM_NAME  "/name_shm_sharedsegment1"

#define BUFSIZE 10000       /*  bounded buffer size */
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE
// #define NUM_ITEMS 10000      /*  total items to produce  */

/* set to 1 to synchronize; 
otherwise set to 0 and see race condition */
#define SYNCHRONIZED 1   // You can play with this and see race

struct buffer{
    struct buffer *next;
    char * buf[BUFSIZE];    // string array
    int count;           /* current number of items in buffer */
    int in; // this field is only accessed by the producer
    int out; // this field is only accessed by the consumer
    int source; // index of the producer
};

struct buffer *head = NULL;
struct buffer *current = NULL;

void printList(){
    struct buffer *ptr = head;

    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("items of buffer %d: \n", ptr->source);
        printf("buffer count is : %d \n", ptr->count);
        printf("buffer in is : %d \n", ptr->in);
        printf("buffer out is : %d \n", ptr->out);                
        for(int i = 0; i < ptr->count; i++){
            printf("%s", ptr->buf[i]);
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void insertFirst(int count, int in, int out, int source){
    struct buffer *link = (struct buffer*) malloc(sizeof(struct buffer));
    for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++){
        link->buf[i] = "";
    }
    link->count = count;
    link->in = in;
    link->out = out;
    link->source = source;

    link->next = head;

    head = link;
}

struct buffer* find(int source){
    struct buffer* current = head;

    if(head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    while(current->source != source){
        if(current->next == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        else{
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return current;
}




#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few semi-random observations.

You define functions in your header file, so if you include that in multiple source files in one project you'll get multiple definition errors from the linker.  (Also, those functions are using standard library functions without including the required header files.)

`main` makes assumptions about the number of parameters passed to the program.  If you don't pass enough, you'll dereference a NULL or out-of-bounds pointer (e.g., an invalid value for `argv[5]`).  You should verify that you have enough parameters (by checking `argc`) before attempting to access any of the parameters.

Rather than the verbose `count_lines = count_lines + 1;`, you can just use `++count_lines;`.

Your code for building the split filename is nearly identical in the two places you use it.  You can put it in a function to avoid the duplication, and simplify it by using `sprintf` to build the entire filename rather than using `sprintf` and `strcat`.

```
sprintf(buf, "splitfile%d.txt", n);
```

where `buf` and `n` are passed as parameters to the function.  `buf` should be long enough to hold any value for `n`, 9 + 4 + 1 + 11 = 25 characters, assuming `n` is no larger than 32 bits.  (That's 9 bytes for the base filename, 4 for the extension, 1 for the terminating nul, and 11 for a signed 32 bit integer printed as a decimal.)

You don't verify that `fw` and `fr` (and some of your other file handles) have successfully been opened before making use of them.

Most of your `strdup` calls will leak, and are not necessary.

At one point in `main` you call `atoi(&line_copy[0])` twice - one inside an `if`, and once in the following statement.  This should be called once, stored in a local variable:

```
int nr = atoi(line_copy);
if (nr > NUMBER_OF_ROWS)
    NUMBER_OF_ROWS = nr;
```

`reducerThread` will be an infinite loop if `SYNCHRONIZED` is 0.